# prevent avplayer from pausing other videos (ie. videos playing in a wkwebview)

Tags: ios, video, concurrency, wkwebview, avplayer

I have a video playing in a wkwebview.

If I start another video playing in a native avplayer instance the wkwebview video pauses.  And vice-versa.

This is within a single app.

Is there a way to allow both to keep playing?

Comment: Good morning, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  At this point we have deemed it unsolveable so had to move to an alternate solution until this changes.

Comment: I've completely forgotten of this thread. I resolved the issue, placing this line ```VAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: [.duckOthers])``` at the start of the app (ie. the SceneDelegate)

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for posting back.  Now I just have to convert that to objective-c and test.  So this keeps the wkwebview videos from pausing even though this is just an AudioSession policy?

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem and it was the solution. I'll post the comment as answer mark it if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, placing this line

```
AVudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: [.duckOthers])
```

at the start of the app (ie. the SceneDelegate)

Comment: I will test when I get a chance and let you know here.  Thanks again.